# I am not able to convert final answer into decimal form

Tags: c#

1. I am not able to bring my final output in decimal terms
2. When i tried to convert double to decimal it gives error

```
     using System;
     namespace Recurring_Deposit_Calc
    {
    class Program
    {
        private double _amount, _month,_a;
        private double _b,_simpleintrest,_matureAmount,_x;
        public void Calulate() {
        Console.WriteLine("Intrest Rate :6.8%");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter amount you deposit per month:");
        _amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter months:");
       _month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Calculting Simple Intrest
        _simpleintrest = _amount * _month*_a/ 2 * 12*_b;
        _a = _month + 1;
        _b = 7.65/100;

        //Calculating Maturity Amount
        _x = _amount * _month;
        _matureAmount = _x + _simpleintrest;
        Console.WriteLine("Amount is :{0}",_matureAmount);
      }
    }
```

[Code link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2pq5Tx)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLGG2.jpg)

Comment: so what's the problem? what error are you encountering?

Comment: After program execution :
Actual Output : 23450 and 
Expected Output : 234.50,so i am confused how to convert the final answer into decimal form

Comment: Unless there is some part of your code you are not showing, I think the `_a` and `_b` variables will always be `0` when they are used in the `_simpleintrest` calculation, resulting in the latter also being `0`, meaning your result will be equal to `_amount * _month`.

Comment: Did you call this calculate method somewhere? What are the values? Please provide us with expected inputs/outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want convert to `decimal`, you can use the [Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Comment: I think OP wants to display the result with decimals, rather than wanting to convert it to a value of type `decimal`. The format string is still invalid if you convert to a `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Amount is :{0}",_matureAmount.ToString("0.00"));
```

If you want upto 1 decimal place, use .ToString("0.0").

Comment: @HansKeﬆing:   Really sorry, a mistake on my side.

Comment: You can include the format string in the placeholder: `Console.WriteLine("Amount is: {0:0.00}", _matureAmount);`

Comment: @Vera:         I usually prefer the ToString way as I've been doing the same since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

1. I got the output as expected
2. New problem how to reduce the place value of final answer

```
        private double p, r = 6.8, i, totalDeposit, maturityAmount;
        private int n;
        public static void Main(string[] args){
             Console.WriteLine("Interest Rate :6.8%");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter per month deposit amount:");
            p = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter months:");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //recurring deposit simple interest formula
            //i=p*(n(n+1)/2*12)*r/100
            i = p * (n * (n + 1) * r / 2400);
            totalDeposit = p * n;
            maturityAmount = totalDeposit + i;
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of maturity = " +
                "Totoal money deposited+Interest:{0}+{1}={2}", totalDeposit, i, maturityAmount);
        }
```

> Output

```
******Recurring Deposit Calculator******
Interest Rate :6.8%
Please enter per month deposit amount:
4567
Enter months:
 7
Amount of maturity = Totoal money 
deposited+Interest:31969+724.6306666666667=32693.630666666668
```